# How to filter/block RSS feed items with SimplePie

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed, simplepie

I've got a google news feed I display in my WordPress site, using the following code:

```
$feed = fetch_feed($rss_url); // specify the source feed
$limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(20); // specify number of items
$items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit); // create an array of items
foreach ($items as $item) : 
    echo $item->get_description(); 
endforeach;
```

Problem is, certain individual articles I need to filter out.  Google news items have guid tags.  Given the guid of the item, how can I tell SimplePie to ignore the given item?

Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimplePie does not have built-in filtering functions (yet). However, you can selectively show only the items you wish:

```
$feed = fetch_feed($rss_url); // specify the source feed
$limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(20); // specify number of items
$items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit); // create an array of items
$ignoreGUIDs = array("http://example.com/feed?id=1", "http://example.com/feed?id=2");
foreach ($items as $item) : 
    if(!in_array($item->get_id(false), $ignoreGUIDs)){
        echo $item->get_description();
    }
endforeach;
```

The [get_id() method](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_id) returns an array of the item's `<guid>`, `<link>`, and `<title>` tags, each of which the `in_array()` clause then searches for a match of each of your `$ignoreGUIDs`. If there are no matches, it means the item's GUID is not in your exlusion list and so the item is shown (by `echo`).

Comment: @Ancide- Surprising that there's no filtering, but your solution is the best option after that.  Thanks for the get_id reference...